RMarkdown cannot creat png file
I am running a RMarkdown report which has many plots at times I get this error "! unable to start png() device". At times the report runs without any issues and at times it breaks at different chunks. Does anyone know what could be causing this? I am using RStudio installed in the HP computer.
I have tried searching for the solution by creating a working directory but still it fails at times and runs without any errors at times.
Thank you!
I have tried searching for the solution by creating a working directory but still it fails at times and runs without any errors at times.
Expecting to get a solution to this issue.

I think you shouldn't expect a solution to this issue unless you can determine what causes it to fail in a reproducible way.  My only guess is that you may have too many open connections.  Run showConnections() to see a list of your open connections.
